# Definite Integral of $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^k+B}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to evaluate the integral

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^k+B} \, \mathrm{d}y
$$

WolframAlpha doesn't return a response even for simplified versions of this, but I believe it can be evaluated through substitution using polar coordinates.  In particular, let the coordinate transformation be define so that

$$
x = r\cos\phi
$$
$$
y = r\sin\phi
$$

and

$$
r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
$$
\phi = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)
$$

From these expressions, I compute the $dy$ differential to be

$$
dy = \frac{dr}{\sin\phi} + \frac{r\,d\phi}{\cos\phi}
$$

so the integral may be written

$$
\int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \sqrt{r^{2k}+B}\left(\frac{dr}{\sin{\phi}} + \frac{rd\phi}{\cos{\phi}}\right)
$$

The indefinite integral of this integrand can be computed with WolframAlpha, though the result is a bit messy.  I can then find the definite integral by evaluating the result at $y=1$ and $y=-1$ and taking the difference of the results.  This could perhaps by simplified by noting that the original integrand is symmetric with respect to a change in the sign of $y$, so the limits of integration could be changed to $y=0$ and $y=1$ and the integral multiplied by $2$.

Are there any apparent errors in this approach to evaluating this integral?

Comment: I guess $dy= \sin \phi \mathrm{d}r+ r \cos \phi \mathrm{d}\phi$ is right!